# Where does the 2048-bit part in Diffie-Hellman key exchange refer to?

Tags: security, diffie-hellman

I have consulted various sources about Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange algorithm, and I have understood the logic behind its operation. However, I have seen the expression "Diffie-Hellman 2048-bit key exchange", and I have a bit of hard time to understand what entity does the value 2048-bit is associated with.

Given the formula:

[image: A=(g^a)mod(p)]

Does it concern:

- the size of prime modulus *p*,
- the size of generated public key *A*,
- or size of the resulted shared secret?

I lean mostly towards the first choice, but I can't verify it by multiple sources. In addition, as far as I know, prime numbers become less and less frequent as one moves towards larger numbers. **If these two statements are true**, then I wonder if the amount of prime numbers, which can be represented by 2048 bits, is adequate for Diffie-Hellman key exchange operation. So, when we choose 2048-bit as the size of *p*, candidate prime numbers for *p* are only those that can be **strictly** represented by 2048-bit, or also prime numbers beyond that?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, DH KEX algorithm requires Alice and Bob decide publicly on two PRIME numbers, `g` and `p` (in your above referenced equation). Generally `g` is a small prime number and `p` is quite large, usually between 2000 and 4000 bits long. As you correctly stated, generating prime numbers with special properties can be computationally heavy, so many implementations use fixed Diffie-Hellman parameters.

As an extra, you can check [weakDH](https://weakdh.org/), that shows a possible attack over a still selectable DH implementation (512-bits long) over TLS protocol, using sieve calculations to get the `p` value of the DH equation.